# Split Dataframe when hyphen appears

Tags: python, dataframe, split

[image]

I have a Dataframe with approx. 70000 rows and 6 columns. The inputs are numbers expect of some hyphens. I want to split the dataframe (by rows) every time a hyphen appears. The row with the hyphen can be deleted.

Example of Dataframe:

```
Timestamp ; power(kW) ; ....
2020-01-01 17:50:10 ; 4.32 ; ... 
2020-01-01 17:55:15 ; 4.30 ; ...
2020-01-01 18:00:20 ; 3.20 ; ...
2020-01-01 18:05:25 ; - ; ...
2020-01-03 12:00:20 ; 6.20 ; ...
```

Expectet Outcome:
2 Dataframe

Comment: Can you show us your dataframe and/or how to create it? Expected output?

Comment: You need to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74140292/edit) the question with the data, you can't post it as comment

Comment: welcome to the stackoverflow!  here is a link to guideline in asking question  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Example of Dataframe:
Timestamp ; power(kW) ; ....
2020-01-01 17:50:10 ; 4.32 ; ... 
2020-01-01 17:55:15 ; 4.30 ; ...
2020-01-01 18:00:20 ; 3.20 ; ...
2020-01-01 18:05:25 ; - ; ...
2020-01-03 12:00:20 ; 6.20 ; ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
# identify rows with "-"
m = df['power(kW)'].eq('-')
# or based on non-numbers:
# m = pd.to_numeric(df['power(kW)'], errors='coerce').isna()

# split per group while removing the invalid rows
subdfs = [d for _,d in df[~m].groupby(m.cumsum())]
```

output list:

```
[             Timestamp power(kW) ....
 0  2020-01-01 17:50:10      4.32  ...
 1  2020-01-01 17:55:15      4.30  ...
 2  2020-01-01 18:00:20      3.20  ...,

              Timestamp power(kW) ....
 4  2020-01-03 12:00:20      6.20  ...]
```

Accessing subdataframes:

```
subdf[0]

             Timestamp power(kW) ....
0  2020-01-01 17:50:10      4.32  ...
1  2020-01-01 17:55:15      4.30  ...
2  2020-01-01 18:00:20      3.20  ...
```

***NB. because your initial data had **strings**, the dtype of the output will be string/object. You must convert the types if you plan to perform vectorial operations.***

One option:

```
subdfs = [d for _,d in df[~m].astype({'Timestamp': 'datetime64',
                                      'power(kW)': float})
                             .groupby(m.cumsum())]
```

Comment: Are you reading the data from file? csv?

Comment: Yes im importing the data as csv

Comment: Then you can try to set `-` as a NaN (check the `read_csv` doc) and use `m = df['power(kW)'].isna()` to try to keep a numeric type

Comment: For another task i need to remain the rows with "-". Is there a way the rows with "-" are not deleted?

Comment: @luscgu00 can you open a new question with your new use case? Make sure to provide a reproducible example (as text, not image!)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74796423/20291779